# Display info from file externally on another site

Tags: php, html, nginx, statistics

Basically I want to have one centralized file (preferably .php or .txt).. In it I will define the version and online statuses of my 3 API's (login, register, and stats)

I will somehow link it to my system status page and call upon them in my html with like $version, $login, $register, or $stats and they will automatically display whatever is defined in the centralized file.

My stats page (https://epicmc.us/status.php).. I want to define it all from a seperate file and call upon it in the HTML.

I tried making an external file called check.php and put this in it:

```
<?php
$version = "1.0.0";
$login = 'online';
$register = 'online';
$stats = 'online';
echo json_encode(compact('version','login','register','stats'));
?>
```

and then in my stats page I called upon it with

```
<?php
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents('https://epicmc.us/api/bridge/check.php'),true);
echo $version;
echo $login;
echo $register;
echo $stats;
?>
```

The page is just blank though.

How would you go about implementing this into my stats page code?
http://pastebin.com/nREdfH1u

Comment: What is the question? how do you fail? what are the errors you get?

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. I will edit this to be a bit more detailed. One second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution here would be to curl your file.

As you already return a JSON string containing your values, just curl your 'check.php' file and json_decode the response.
One of the advantages of this method is that you can access these informations from other domains.
You should be able to get all the values easily.

Example :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'check.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to return the response in a variable and not output it
// $result contains the output string
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
$array_response = json_decode($result, true);

// echo $array_response['version']...
```

Comment: I'm kinda new to this.. When you say "curl your file" how do I do that? Sorry if that's noobie but I have no idea how to approach that. Is this a code that goes in my check.php or does it go in my status page?

Comment: This code should go in your status page. Curl will "ping" your 'check.php' file, execute it, and get the response.